# capture all iterations of repeated matching groups using java regex pattern matcher

Tags: java, regex

I see few examples but none this complex and specific to Java; hence repeating, if I may.

https://regex101.com/r/DbYiB0/1/

See link above for an attempt to extract values using regex pattern. It seem to capture only the last iteration of the matched group.

I have better result with .Net version at [http://regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%28%5Cd%7B2%7D%2F%5Cd%7B2%7D%2F%5Cd%7B4%7D%29%3B%5Cs%28%5Cw%2B%29%3B%5Cs%2B%28%28%5Cw%2B%29%3B%5Cs%5C%24%28%5Cd%2B%5C.%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%5Cs%2B%29*%29*&i=21%2F09%2F2017%3B%20INV1%3B%20%0D%0AITEM1%3B%20%24115.45%0D%0AITEM2%3B%20%249.00%0D%0AITEM3%3B%20%240.65%0D%0A21%2F09%2F2017%3B%20INV2%3B%20%0D%0AITEM1%3B%20%241.55%0D%0AITEM2%3B%20%247.25%0D%0AITEM3%3B%20%242.05%0D%0AITEM4%3B%20%240.05%0D%0A)

Comment: It would be a great help if you explained what you're trying to do.

Comment: The attempt is to extract the data. I know it can be done using split but this is a trivialized example of a complex case I need to deal with.

Comment: Which part of which data? How are we supposed to offer a solution to an undefined problem?

Comment: You probably did not click the link in the post. The regular expression and data to be matched, is at https://regex101.com/r/DbYiB0/1/.

Comment: Of course I did (though I shouldn't have to). But you've indicated that you're not satisfied with how it's matching. So how should we know what you were expecting?

Comment: I am expecting to extract all data not only the last iterations of the matches. Hope that is clear now. If not, click on both links in the post and see the difference between the results, the Table tab in regexstorm.net shows all the data extracted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it captures the last match if there are repeating matches.
As I know, it's impossible to do only with regex, you might match every line in your program and grab the values you want with regex.
You can also group all items and then split them in your program.

Comment: If it works in .Net then I suppose it would in Java too; just that I am not a regex guru.